# Get count of arrays returned in $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

Seems like a simple question but can't find a result anywhere in JQuery help or on SO. How do I get the count of the number of arrays returned from JSON array. `cust_id` may return 2 arrays or as many as 10.

```
$.each(data, function() {
       if (this.cust_id == selectedProductAutonum) {
         invoices = this;                                         
         return true;
         alert(this.length);
       }
 });
```

example JSON:

```
var myjson = [{
    "autonum": "20",
    "date": "2017-03-22",
    "customer": "Jeffs Music\r\n",
    "address": "Montgomery Station",
    "invoice": "20160929",
    "sales": "2416.00",
    "paid": "1000.00",
    "owed": "1416.00",
    "tax": "0.00",
    "misc": "2017-03-22 19:51:00",
    "cust_id": "15",
    "product": "Labor",
    "description": "Complete Install Labor only (DVR configuration, Install, Pow",
    "cost": "2150.00",
    "quantity": "1",
    "price": "2150.00",
    "timestamp": "2017-03-22 19:51:00"
}, {
    "autonum": "21",
    "date": "2017-03-22",
    "customer": "Jeffs Music\r\n",
    "address": "Montgomery Station",
    "invoice": "20160929",
    "sales": "2416.00",
    "paid": "1000.00",
    "owed": "1416.00",
    "tax": "0.00",
    "misc": "2017-03-22 19:51:00",
    "cust_id": "15",
    "product": "Home Depot",
    "description": "Home Depot Supplies for Shelf/mounts/braces/paint.",
    "cost": "128.50",
    "quantity": "1",
    "price": "128.50",
    "timestamp": "2017-03-22 19:51:00"
}, {
    "autonum": "22",
    "date": "2017-03-22",
    "customer": "Mikes Music\r\n",
    "address": "Montgomery Station",
    "invoice": "20160929",
    "sales": "2416.00",
    "paid": "1000.00",
    "owed": "1416.00",
    "tax": "0.00",
    "misc": "2017-03-22 19:51:00",
    "cust_id": "15",
    "product": "Cables",
    "description": "Cables and Connectors / power pigtails",
    "cost": "43.85",
    "quantity": "1",
    "price": "43.85",
    "timestamp": "2017-03-22 19:51:00"
}, {
    "autonum": "23",
    "date": "2017-03-22",
    "customer": "Jeffs Music\r\n",
    "address": "Montgomery Station",
    "invoice": "20160929",
    "sales": "2416.00",
    "paid": "1000.00",
    "owed": "1416.00",
    "tax": "0.00",
    "misc": "2017-03-22 19:51:00",
    "cust_id": "10",
    "product": "Cables",
    "description": "Cables and connectors / hardware used in November 2016",
    "cost": "45.55",
    "quantity": "1",
    "price": "45.55",
    "timestamp": "2017-03-22 19:51:00"
}, {
    "autonum": "24",
    "date": "2017-03-22",
    "customer": "Jeffs Music\r\n",
    "address": "Montgomery Station",
    "invoice": "20160929",
    "sales": "2416.00",
    "paid": "1000.00",
    "owed": "1416.00",
    "tax": "0.00",
    "misc": "2017-03-22 19:51:00",
    "cust_id": "10",
    "product": "Cables",
    "description": "Extension power supply cables",
    "cost": "43.12",
    "quantity": "1",
    "price": "43.12",
    "timestamp": "2017-03-22 19:51:00"
}]
```

Comment: This is unclear!

Comment: Looking your code, you can do this `data.find(({cust_id}) => cust_id === selectedProductAutonum)`

Comment: There is a typo in your code.  You're missing the closing bracket of the if condition.

Comment: *the count of the number of arrays* - `myjson` is only one array with multiple objects

Comment: @Ele Note, `.find()` returns at most one element of an array.

Comment: @guest271314 yes, the OP is returning just when a `cust_id` is found.  So, the OP's logic is finding a specific object.  As I said, this is unclear!

Comment: Why is there a return true before the alert?

Comment: @Ele The input is an array of objects. Given OP asks about `.length`, can you be sure there is not more than a single unique property name in the entire array of objects and  OP is not expecting more than a single `"cust_id"` property value to be returned?

Comment: if `cust_id==15` it should return 3 if `cust_id==10` it shoud return 2

Comment: will `data.find(({cust_id}) => cust_id === selectedProductAutonum)` return the count or the data? I need the count

Comment: @guest271314 that returns the count of 7 (the full data json)

Comment: @guest271314 looking for the count of the requested cust_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function `filter` to get a array of objects which have `cust_id === "10"`.

```js
var myjson = [{    "autonum": "20",    "date": "2017-03-22",    "customer": "Jeffs Music\r\n",    "address": "Montgomery Station",    "invoice": "20160929",    "sales": "2416.00",    "paid": "1000.00",    "owed": "1416.00",    "tax": "0.00",    "misc": "2017-03-22 19:51:00",    "cust_id": "15",    "product": "Labor",    "description": "Complete Install Labor only (DVR configuration, Install, Pow",    "cost": "2150.00",    "quantity": "1",    "price": "2150.00",    "timestamp": "2017-03-22 19:51:00"}, {    "autonum": "21",    "date": "2017-03-22",    "customer": "Jeffs Music\r\n",    "address": "Montgomery Station",    "invoice": "20160929",    "sales": "2416.00",    "paid": "1000.00",    "owed": "1416.00",    "tax": "0.00",    "misc": "2017-03-22 19:51:00",    "cust_id": "15",    "product": "Home Depot",    "description": "Home Depot Supplies for Shelf/mounts/braces/paint.",    "cost": "128.50",    "quantity": "1",    "price": "128.50",    "timestamp": "2017-03-22 19:51:00"}, {    "autonum": "22",    "date": "2017-03-22",    "customer": "Mikes Music\r\n",    "address": "Montgomery Station",    "invoice": "20160929",    "sales": "2416.00",    "paid": "1000.00",    "owed": "1416.00",    "tax": "0.00",    "misc": "2017-03-22 19:51:00",    "cust_id": "15",    "product": "Cables",    "description": "Cables and Connectors / power pigtails",    "cost": "43.85",    "quantity": "1",    "price": "43.85",    "timestamp": "2017-03-22 19:51:00"}, {    "autonum": "23",    "date": "2017-03-22",    "customer": "Jeffs Music\r\n",    "address": "Montgomery Station",    "invoice": "20160929",    "sales": "2416.00",    "paid": "1000.00",    "owed": "1416.00",    "tax": "0.00",    "misc": "2017-03-22 19:51:00",    "cust_id": "10",    "product": "Cables",    "description": "Cables and connectors / hardware used in November 2016",    "cost": "45.55",    "quantity": "1",    "price": "45.55",    "timestamp": "2017-03-22 19:51:00"}, {    "autonum": "24",    "date": "2017-03-22",    "customer": "Jeffs Music\r\n",    "address": "Montgomery Station",    "invoice": "20160929",    "sales": "2416.00",    "paid": "1000.00",    "owed": "1416.00",    "tax": "0.00",    "misc": "2017-03-22 19:51:00",    "cust_id": "10",    "product": "Cables",    "description": "Extension power supply cables",    "cost": "43.12",    "quantity": "1",    "price": "43.12",    "timestamp": "2017-03-22 19:51:00"}],
    selectedProductAutonum = "10",
    result = myjson.filter(({cust_id}) => cust_id === selectedProductAutonum);
    
console.log("Length:", result.length);

selectedProductAutonum = "15";
result = myjson.filter(({cust_id}) => cust_id === selectedProductAutonum);

console.log("Length:", result.length);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter()`

```
const filterProp = (data, prop, match) => data.filter(({[prop]:p}) => p == match)
let selectedProductAutonum = "15"
let {length: len} = filterProp(myjson, "cust_id", selectedProductAutonum)
console.log(len)
```

Comment: where am I putting this in my example?

Comment: You can substitute using built-in `Array.prototype.filter()` for `jQuery.each()`. You can adjust the code to avoid having to get `.length` from the function by returning `.length` `const filterPropLength = (data, prop, match) => data.filter(({[prop]:p}) => p == match).length;
let selectedProductAutonum = "15";
let len = filterPropLength(myjson, "cust_id", selectedProductAutonum);
console.log(len);`

Comment: I need a solution for the .each

Comment: @BarclayVision _"I need a solution for the .each"_ Why? `jQuery.each()`  is not necessary.

Comment: accepted anwser from @Ele - Your aksing why can't I change my question? my question is how to make it work with $.each

Comment: @BarclayVision You can use whichever approach you decide to. _"my question is how to make it work with $.each"_ `let len = 0;
jQuery.each(myjson, function(key, value) {
  if (value.cust_id == selectedProductAutonum) {
    ++len;
  }
});

console.log(len)`